# Generating simple RSS feed from parsed data

Tags: python, django, loops, python-2.7, rss

Hello Stack Overflow I have some code that scrapes a website and parses small sections of data as below;

```
System MA
user id =  2084
username =  XYZ90
selection =  pnq
decimal =  6.000
Percentage =  19.1176470588 %

System NA
user id =  2086
username =  pron1
selection =  abc
decimal =  13.000
Percentage =  13.1147540984 %

System M
user id =  1664
username =  Chrisod
selection =  pleader
decimal =  15.000
Percentage =  16.091954023 %
```

The above is printed as a result of the following filters:

```
if (deciaml > 5 and percentage > 10:
    print "system", system_acn
    print "user id = ",user_id
    print "username = ",username
    print "selection = ",selection
    print "decimal = ",decimal_delim   
    print "percentage = ,percentage_calc2,"%"
```

This is all as a results of printing different parameters from a looping webscraper. What I want to be able to do is to is export each as an RSS. So the above would exist as three RSS posts, within the RSS feed. I have researched some modules such as django, this seems to be a toolkit for many things not specifically RSS, essentially what I am looking for the simplest and easiest RSS solution possible? Any advice or comments on suitable methodologies and or modules would be greatly appreciated. 
Kind regards AEA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed you have tagged your question as pertaining to Django. If you are going to build a Django application based on this problem, then the [syndication framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/) is what you want to use. However, this isn't worth it unless you are planning to use other components of Django, such as the database stuff and / or the template language.

However, you asked for the "simplest and easiest" solution. I love Django and it only takes me minutes to set up an app so for me the easiest way to do your whole project would probably be to make a quick Django app. The simplest solution is probably to create the feed manually, shouldn't be that hard; something like:

```
inp="""System MA
user id =  2084
username =  XYZ90
selection =  pnq
decimal =  6.000
Percentage =  19.1176470588 %

System NA
user id =  2086
username =  pron1
selection =  abc
decimal =  13.000
Percentage =  13.1147540984 %

System M
user id =  1664
username =  Chrisod
selection =  pleader
decimal =  15.000
Percentage =  16.091954023 %"""

inp=inp.split('\n\n')

rss_start="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<rss version="2.0">

<channel>
  <title>Your title</title>
  <link>http://yoursite.com</link>
  <description>Your discription</description>
"""

rss_end="""</channel>

</rss> """

def description(item):
    return item

def title(item):
    return item.split('\n')[0]

def link(item):
    return 'http://mysite.com/' + item.split('\n')[0]

rss_items=[]
for counter, item in enumerate(inp):
    rss_items.append("""
  <item>
    <title>%s</title>
    <link>%s</link>
    <description>%s</description>
    <guid>counter</guid>
  </item>""" % (title(item),description(item),link(item)))

rss_output=rss_start+''.join(rss_items)+rss_end
```

You probably also want to add `<pubDate>` tags. And make sure your `<guid>`s are unique.

Note: rss template copied from w3schools.com

Comment: Hello foobarbecue I have made some edits to my question, mainly because the comments don't allow code to be formatted in an aesthetically pleasing way. How would I get the filtered printing section to yield the results in such a way that would be compatible with the supplied `inp=` prefix? Kind regards AEA

Comment: Instead of printing, you should add your filtered results to some kind of variable, such as a list or a dictionary. I've started with a string variable called "inp" which was just my shorthand for "input." Then I split up the string into a list of strings each time there are two newline characters in a row using .split('\n\n') . You could just build up inp as a list, using inp=[] and then inp.append() in your if statement. If you like, I can edit my answer to add this code, but what you are asking for is pretty basic python.

Comment: I have to get my code outputting as a variable before I can test this code properly, I will of course remember to upvote and accept your answer if it works :)